# Cocoapod installed not under /usr/local/bin/, why?

Tags: ruby, macos, cocoapods

I installed `ruby` with:

```
$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

I installed `cocoapod` with `$ sudo gem install cocoapods`

so `$ pod env` shows me:

````
### Stack

```
   CocoaPods : 1.1.1
        Ruby : ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x86_64-darwin16]
    RubyGems : 2.6.8
        Host : Mac OS X 10.12.2 (16C68)
       Xcode : 8.2 (8C38)
         Git : git version 2.10.1 (Apple Git-78)
Ruby lib dir : /Users/snaggs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib
Repositories : master - https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git @ 809d86f6e2c2b68cb138cb1609bebe3357401c4e
```

### Installation Source

```
Executable Path: /Users/snaggs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/bin/pod
```

### Plugins

```
cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.1
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.0
cocoapods-stats       : 1.0.0
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.1.2
cocoapods-try         : 1.1.0
````

but I need `pod` Executable Path under `/usr/local/bin/` for Jenkins.

Do I need to run additional install `cocoapod`  to `/usr/local/bin/`?

And why from other examples I see pod installed under `/usr/local/bin/` and mine `/Users/snaggs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/bin/pod`?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

```
$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

This isn't how you installed `ruby`. This is to install `homebrew`.

From your `pod env` outputs, you have an rvm installed ruby, under home directory. And `cocoapod` is installed under that, like any other gem. This is the default path for any ruby gem, no surprise.

Though I have little knowledge about `Jenkins`, it is hardly to believe `Jenkins` only works for `/usr/local/bin/pod`.

If you don't know how to configure `Jenkins` for cocoapods, I suggest just create a symbol link under `/usr/local/bin` for `pod`.

Another alternative is to install pod by `gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods`. `-n` indicates directory where binary files are located.